# Total Derivative Notation and Optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

I came across the following notation for a total derivative: $$\textbf{D}^2f(\textbf{a})(\textbf{u})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n f''_{x_j x_i}(\textbf{a})u_iu_j$$ where $\textbf{u} = (dx_1, dx_2,\ldots,dx_n)$.

I understand what this is saying, but my confusion lies in the vector $\textbf{u}$ and the following statement:

> If $\textbf{D}^2f(\textbf{a})(\textbf{u})^2$ > 0 for all $\textbf{u} \neq \textbf{0}$, then $f$ has a relative minimum at $\textbf{a}$.

How can a vector of differentials ever be zero? Since $\textbf{a}$ and $f$ are fixed, what exactly are we checking here?

EDIT: After thinking about it is $\textbf{u}$ supposed to denote the differential of *any* vector? Hence the above must hold for all nonzero vectors?

Comment: This is extremely ugly and unintuitive notation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It is from a textbook, but I agree

Comment: I mean... why the *second* superscript $\mbox{}^2$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I suppose to emphasize that there are two differentials being mixed $u_iu_j$

Comment: What textbook is this from? A more standard way to say this would be: "Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is twice continuously differentiable and $\nabla f(a) = 0$. If the Hessian matrix $Hf(a)$ is positive definite, then $a$ is a local minimizer for $f$."

Comment: @littleO Advanced Calculus by Petrovic